# Show the number of triangles in a random graph follows Poisson

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Define a random graph $\Bbb G(n,p)$ as a graph with $n$ vertices where an edge between two vertices occur with probability $p$. Let $X$ be the number of triangles in the random graph, show that if $p=c/n$ ($c$ is a non-negative constant), then $X$ asymptotically follows Poisson distribution as $n \to \infty$.

Can anyone provide some help? Thank you!

Comment: @A.S. This is not entirely accurate. Some triangles share sides, so that such configurations are not independent binomials. The distribution can be shown to be Poisson via something like the Chern-Stein method because these covariances can be shown to be negligible.

Comment: @Alex You are correct. I rushed. The number of triangles is not simply Binomial but will converge to the Poisson mentioned due to limited-range dependencies.

Comment: @A.S. I also realized this is not a trivial i.i.d Bernoulli problem. Can you help provide a reference or a more detailed answer? Thank you!

Comment: @Sherry: check out this book: http://www.amazon.com/The-Probabilistic-Method-Noga-Alon/dp/0470170204

Comment: See [this](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~psdey/414CourseNotes.pdf), and adapt Example 7.3.

Comment: @Sherry: If you don't want to use the Chern Stein method, there is a method of moments approach as well. See here: http://cims.nyu.edu/~nica/RandomGraphsSpencer.pdf